# Android Password Hashing

Tags: android, hash, authentication, passwords

I don't know if I got this right but it seems to me that no one ever put together some guidelines about how to correctly salt and hash passwords on Android for creating a simple login mechanism.

I just came up with this as I wanted to make a rather simple(?) Android app involving user authentication for Web API access.

I can't seem to find any solution on appropriate BCrypt/SHA256 libs...

I found a Java Library offering BCrypt but as soon as I get to the point actually executing the hash function my Android seems to freeze due to insufficient resources available. What kind of password encryption are Facebook/Twitter/Snapchat etc using?

I would never send such parameters plain text!

Comment: You should send password as plain text over https. see [this post](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/8596/)

Comment: Salting and hashing is done on the system that is performing the authentication. In your environment, is an Android device performing the authentication, or is some server performing the authentication?

Comment: If you do in fact need to use BCrypt, as you have found it is very intensive computationally. Best to do is to execute this on a background thread and display progress or some other UI to indicate to users they should wait.

Comment: Well then...so users must actually trust the server owner? That's very ironic at some point of view.

Comment: @Flash1232 Yes, users must actually trust the server owner and admin staff as well as a secure and up-to-date server environment. Sending a hashed password does not really help, the hash just becomes the password, that is what is sent to the server. Creating a password verifier from the password should take about 100ms of CPU time on the server.

Comment: @zaph I would do both on Desktop or Web Apps as I want to revoke any responsibility for password (hash) leaks. Clearly a hashed password can be intercepted and used on my platform aswell but as I might use a salt it is not usable on other platforms unless reversing the client and performing a lookup on a rainbow table or performing any kind of computational attack on the hash.

Comment: The general practice is to send the plain password in HTTPS post data to the server. On the server a password specific hashing method is used that requires ~100ms of CPU tine, NIST recommends PBKDF2, for PHP the pair `password_hash` and `password_verify` are a secure method. More security can be obtained, again as suggested by NIST, by not allowing well known passwords. Beyond this is tilting at windmills that very likely will reduce security.

Comment: You need to develop a threat model, that is who are you protecting against and what is the value that is being protected. Are you protecting against spear-fishing attacks or an attacker who want's bulk user credentials? Or does the attacker want access to server or user data?

Comment: @zaph Thanks very much for your considerable inputs! Generally speaking, I just want the user to have maximum transparency in my service and best possible protection against any kind of attack (which - is not possible for obvious reasons).

Comment: Can you afford an [HSM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_security_module)? Is the server protected with [OTP hardware tokens](https://www.logintc.com/docs/guides/hardware.html)? Or is your security need not that high.

Comment: For Best Practices see: [Digital Identity Guidelines](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/SpecialPublications/NIST.SP.800-63b.pdf)
[Digital Identity Guidelines](https://pages.nist.gov/800-63-3/), [NIST’s new password rules](https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2016/08/18/nists-new-password-rules-what-you-need-to-know/), [How to store your users’ passwords safely](https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2013/11/20/serious-security-how-to-store-your-users-passwords-safely/), NIST [Recommendation for Password-Based Key Derivation](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/Legacy/SP/nistspecialpublication800-132.pdf).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152563/discussion-between-flash1232-and-zaph).

Comment: Simply use Best Practices, these were developed and vetted be knowledgable people and been well vetted by well versed individuals. Without years of supervised cryptographic experience it is not possible to do better, only worse.
["Schneier's Law"](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2011/04/schneiers_law.html): "*Anyone, from the most clueless amateur to the best cryptographer, can create an algorithm that he himself can't break.*"

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of different approach, but the most convenient way is to send your password over HTTPS to your server then your actual hashing should be done on the server thus hashing is a CPU consuming operation.

However you can implement another way, in this scenario you execute your hashing function on the client side (mobile) and then send your hashed value to your server and you have the option to hash your hashed password once again to make it even more secure but keep in mind hashing your password on the client side may impress your UX, and you'd better handle it on an appropriate way.

so as you might guess there is no one-way rule, it actually depends on your choice.